# How to get timezone name in outlook appointment using office.js

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

is there way to get timezome name of current outlook item using outlook add-in as below ?

```
let name= Office.context.mailbox.item.start.timeZoneName;
```

[image: outlook]

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible today. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page.
It looks like the feature you want has been requested by others already. Please upvote the existing request https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/38501812-provide-api-to-get-event-start-end-time-zone-usin. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it myself (yet), but you should be able to get the saved timezome information by [using the rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/use-rest-api) to [get an event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/calendar-rest-operations#GetEvent), which includes the timezone of the start & end times.